# $(document).on() only works on one dynamic element, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

this is my first question on Stack, even though I've been a fan for years. Please bear with me, I hope my question is clear.

I'm using this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkbox img", function () {
   // object
   var checkbox = $(this).next("input[type=checkbox]");
   // check if checked
   if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
       checkbox.prop("checked", false); this.src = "http://imgs.airwalk-design.com/layout/chckno.png";
   } else {
       checkbox.prop("checked", true); this.src = "http://imgs.airwalk-design.com/layout/chckyes.png";
   }
});
```

Which works lovely. However, if the user closes the form (it slides out, removed from DOM), and opens another one (ajax, inserted into DOM), the checkboxes do not work on that form. I can, though, re-open the first form and the checkboxes work on that one, even though it's been removed and appended again.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

**MackieeE's answer/comment worked for me. I used "#uniqueformid #checkbox img" instead.**

Comment: How many times is the ID `checkbox` used?

Comment: Use a class instead of an id for `.checkbox img`

Comment: Well, there are two id's, but only one in the DOM at a time. The forms are being switched. I tried switching to a class, nonetheless, but it didn't work. I can use the code on any checkbox successfully, but never a second form.

Comment: Add a small timestamp or a small guid to each form upon creation, `"#someid .checkbox img"`

Comment: Brilliant, this worked. Since the the ajax code was used on many different forms, I used form = $(newElems); var formId = form.find("form").attr("id"); var specChck = "#" + formId + " #checkbox img"; this to detect which form was loaded into the DOM. Cheers mate.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz No problems =]!

Answer (score 1):

```
#checkbox
```

is an id and therefore there can only be one occurrence of it, this is probably the reason why it's not working when you insert a second form. Try using a class instead.

Comment: I tried that, nothing. There is only one occurrence of the id in the DOM at a time. Does that make a difference?